# How to add features after applying sort in mongolite in R

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

```
sorted <- m$find(sort = '{"forks_count": -1}',
             limit = 10)
```

How do I select only 3 features such as name, age, and income after applying the sort on the forks_count?

Answer (score 0):

In standard MongoDB nomenclature, this is referred to as projection. General information about that is found on [this page in their documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).

Taking a look at the Mongolite User Manual, it seems like that project uses [the `fields` parameter](https://jeroen.github.io/mongolite/query-data.html#filter-fields) to provide this functionality. Based on that documentation, it looks like you can change your query to something similar to the following to get the results that you want:

```
sorted <- m$find(sort = '{"forks_count": -1}',
             fields = '{"name" : true, "age" : true, "income" : true}',
             limit = 10)
```

Note that depending on exactly what format you want your results in, you may also want to suppress the `_id` value (eg make it `false`).